# stop an video at specific time and onclick it should start from end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, mediaelement.js

**HI,
How to stop an video at specific time and if user wants to play video should start?
 I stop the video but i cant start the video from i stoped will you please help me ?**

my code following below:

```
     MediaElement('player1', {success: function(me) {
                     var endtime = 4;
                     var me = document.getElementById('player1');         
                    me.play();

                    me.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
                        if (this.currentTime >= endtime) {
            this.pause();
        }

                        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = me.currentTime;
                    }, false);


                }});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is [remove your event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) with `me.removeEventListener()`.

Another possibility is to set a flag (see "alreadystopped" in the example below) once the video has been stopped, and add a check for that flag:

```
MediaElement('player1', {success: function(me) {
    var endtime = 4;
    var alreadyStopped = false;
    var me = document.getElementById('player1');         
    me.play();

    me.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        if (this.currentTime >= endtime && !alreadyStopped) {
            this.pause();
            alreadyStopped = true;
        }

        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = me.currentTime;
    }, false);
}});
```

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Google is your frind "java script start an stop vidios" and you aren't need to write someting right

```
function vidplay() {
   var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
   var button = document.getElementById("play");
      video.currentTime= xy;//it could be that it have an other name
      video.play();
      button.textContent = "||";
}
```

Comment: from this link only i just stop an video and tried that restart function also not yet getting

Comment: No change it remains same

Comment: In my post i pasted my code in that u just tell me the solution

Comment: I want a soluion to start from end of the video

Comment: ok i give up it is to complicte cto comine this ten lines i will update it